# Cannot save modified frames with Python OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I wrote this code to take a video file as input from my local storage, then display it and re-encode the frames in grayscale and save it to an output file. Here is my code:

```py
import cv2 as cv

fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25.0, (640,  480))
cap = cv.VideoCapture(input())
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error opening video file")
    exit()
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame. Exiting ...")
        break

    frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #This line is causing the problem
    out.write(frame)
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

With this code, I can see the video file being played, but the output file appears blank. It works if I write the original `frame` object into the output file. But, whenever I use `frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` to convert the frame into grayscale, it does not work and I get a blank output file. What mistake am I doing?

Comment: Just a guess, and hence not an answer, but maybe your writer expects 3 channels rather than one. Try writing with `out.write(np.dstack((frame,frame,frame)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the cv docs, [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html) the signature of VideoWriter constructor is

```
VideoWriter (const String &filename, int fourcc, double fps, Size frameSize, bool isColor=true)
```

i.e. if you're writing a grayscale image, you need to set the isColor param to false since it's true by default. Replace the line with this,

```
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25.0, (640,  480), 0)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works. Just one more question does the `framesize` parameter has to be equal to the original video size? Because if I give anything other than the original size, still I get a blank file output.

Comment: It needs to be equal to the size of each frame you're writing to the video. So doesn't have to be of the same size as the original. If you want a video of different frame size, make sure you resize each frame before writing.